# running bash script in network namespace with systemd and selinux enforcing?

Tags: linux, bash, systemd, selinux

I have a script that needs to run in a network namespace (ip netns exec), and I have written a systemd service file.

It fails to start however, journalctl -xe reports:

ip[7918]: exec of "/usr/share/stats/run_collect.sh" failed: Permission denied

The service file is executing the command as (it is an instantiated service)

```
ExecStart=/sbin/ip netns exec ns%i /usr/share/stats/run_collect.sh %i
```

Selinux is in mode enforcing, and to get it working I have to run `semanage permissive -a ifconfig_t`.
Without that the script is not executed,

In my different attempts, I got in a situation, which I cannot reproduce, where the script started but
then failed  because the tcpdump process started by the script missed the correct selinux context to
write to a log file in /var/log/stats/. (I think I got in that situation when I had issued
`semanage fcontext -a -t ifconfig_exec_t /usr/share/stats/run_collect.sh` and applying it with `restorecon -Frvv /usr/share/stats/`. Repeating this doesn't work though....)

What's the best approach to get this working without setting the ifconfig_t domain as permissive?